# boolean value doesn't change after a function is called whenever a button is clicked

Tags: angular, function, button, click, components

I have two angular components, one of them must be shown if a search button in the first one is clicked. But unfortunately the code I did doesn't work and only work when I change the boolean value "clicked" manually.
Can anyone help me in that ?

the structure of my components is like that:

```
src
 |app
   |components
      |FilterBarComponent
      |LogTableComponent
```

the code of the search button in FilterBarComponent:

```
<button class="btn-search text-center"  (click)="buttonStatus = 
!buttonStatus">Search</button>
```

FilterBarComponenet.ts:

```
export class FilterBarComponent implements OnInit {
  buttonStatus: boolean;

  constructor(private logsService: HttpClientTestService) {
    this.buttonStatus = false;
  }
```

LogsTableComponent.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FilterBarComponent } from './../filter-bar/filter-bar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-logs-table',
  templateUrl: './logs-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logs-table.component.css']
})
export class LogsTableComponent implements OnInit {
  clicked: boolean;
  constructor(private filterBar: FilterBarComponent) { }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getButtonStatus() {
    this.clicked = this.filterBar.buttonStatus;
  }

}
```

LogsTableComponent.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid p-2" *ngIf="clicked">
```

Comment: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: your `getButtonStatus()` is neither invoked nor it is listening to changes, consider using observables.

Comment: I already read your article (a good one btw) but it is always about parent/child components, is there any communication way to share data between two components in the same structure level ?

Comment: Nope There isn't Have a look https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a structure:

```
`-App Component
 -Log Table Component
 -Filter Bar Component`
```

An App Component is responsible for communication between Log and Filter Component

app.component.ts

```
`export class AppComponent {
   public clickedEvent: boolean;

   childEventClicked(event: boolean) {
     this.clickedEvent = event;
   }
}`
```

app.component.html

```
`<div style="text-align:center">
  <app-filter-bar (eventClicked)="childEventClicked($event)"></app-filter-bar>
  <app-log-table [clicked]="clickedEvent"></app-log-table>
</div>`
```

filter-bar.component.ts

```
`export class FilterBarComponent implements OnInit {
  public buttonStatus: boolean = false;
  @Output() eventClicked: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick(event: boolean): void {
    this.buttonStatus = !event;
    this.eventClicked.emit(this.buttonStatus);
  }
}`
```

filter-bar.component.html

`<button class="btn-search text-center"  (click)="onClick(buttonStatus)">
  button status: {{buttonStatus}}
</button>`

log-table.component.ts

```
export class LogTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() clicked: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

log-table.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid p-2" *ngIf="clicked">Test</div>
```

Check this answer

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved my day, I was struggling with that and everyone telling me that you can't share data between two components having the same structure level. Thank you again for your time

Comment: @Boha Perhaps You did not go through the documentation properly ;|

Comment: @Vikas May be , I'm pressed by time :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the function `getButtonStatus` called anywhere in your code. May be that's the issue. You need to call it in `ngOnInit` I guess.
Also You are injecting a component into another via constructor. That does not work in angular, you should pass by a service.